How to optimize and refactor C# method for validating business rules in terms of readability, maintainability, and performance?
I'm working on a C# project and have a bloater method ValidateBusinessRules that checks a series of business rules for validating the operations. The current code is difficult to maintain, lacks readability, and likely has performance inefficiencies. I'm seeking advice on how to refactor and optimize this code in terms of:
Readability: The method is quite long and has complex conditions.
Maintainability: Adding or modifying rules should be easy.
Performance: The method contains several external calls to helper classes, DAL methods, and date manipulations, which may affect performance.
Here’s the current code:
public bool ValidateBusinessRules(RCMTFDBusinessEntity objTfdEntity, List<RCMRolloutRulesBusinessEntity> listBusinessRules, RCMTFDConfigBusinessEntity tfdConfig, bool isSetInterimRulesSupported,
                                    out string businessRuleFailed, out string reason, out bool isBRToBeRetried, out Int16 tfdReason, bool isTFDCommandSupported = false)
{
    RCMTFDDAL objTFDDal = new RCMTFDDAL();
    reason = null;
    tfdReason = (Int16)RCMApplicationConstants.TFDReason.ProcessNotstartedDueToBRFailure;
    isBRToBeRetried = true;
    bool IsRuleValid = true;
    int cLoop = 0;
    bool bufferETARuleSuccess = false;
    businessRuleFailed = null;
    string commandName = isSetInterimRulesSupported ? RcmFwdCmdConstants.SetInterimTempCommandName : isTFDCommandSupported ? RcmFwdCmdConstants.TerminalFreezeDown : RcmFwdCmdConstants.ChangeTempCmdName; //  Using TerminalFreezeDown constant for checking command for TFD
    RCMHelper objHelper = new RCMHelper();
    RCMHelperDAL objRCMHelperDal = new RCMHelperDAL();
    while (IsRuleValid && cLoop < listBusinessRules.Count)
    {
        RCMLogHandler.LogInfo("BusinessRule Being Validate: " + listBusinessRules[cLoop].Name, RCMLogHandler.LogType.General);
        businessRuleFailed = listBusinessRules[cLoop].Name.ToLower();
        switch (listBusinessRules[cLoop].Name.ToLower())
        {
            case RCMApplicationConstants.IsReeferTFDCapable:
                if (listBusinessRules[cLoop].Value.Equals(RCMApplicationConstants.ConfigValueYes, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
                {
                    if (!objHelper.IsReeferTFDCapable(objTfdEntity.ContainerNumber))
                    {
                        IsRuleValid = false;
                        isBRToBeRetried = false;
                        reason = RCMApplicationConstants.ReeferNotCapableForTFD;// "Reefer is not capable for TFD process";
                        tfdReason = (Int16)RCMApplicationConstants.TFDReason.TFDNotEnabled;
                    }
                }
                break;
            case RCMApplicationConstants.OemSupported:
                if (listBusinessRules[cLoop].Value.Equals(RCMApplicationConstants.ConfigValueYes, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
                {
                    if (!objHelper.IsForwardCommandSupported(RCMApplicationConstants.TerminalFreezeDown, objTfdEntity.ContainerId))
                    {
                        IsRuleValid = false;
                        isBRToBeRetried = false;
                        reason = RCMApplicationConstants.OEMNotSupportedForTFD;// "TFD process not allowed for OEM,UnitType and ControllerType for this container";
                        tfdReason = (Int16)RCMApplicationConstants.TFDReason.TFDNotEnabled;
                    }
                }
                break;
            case RCMApplicationConstants.ForwardCommandSupported:
                if (!objHelper.IsForwardCommandSupported(commandName, objTfdEntity.ContainerId))
                {
                    IsRuleValid = false;
                    isBRToBeRetried = false;
                    reason = RCMApplicationConstants.FWDCmdNotSupported;// "Forward Command not supported for this container";
                    tfdReason = (Int16)RCMApplicationConstants.TFDReason.TFDNotEnabled;
                }
                break;

            case RCMApplicationConstants.ContainerPowerOn:
                if (objTfdEntity.PowerIndicator != RCMApplicationConstants.PowerIndicatorOn)
                {
                    // Code to handle, if container power indicator is OFF but unit telemetry is recieving in RCM EC in last configured hours then will allow reefer for further processing. 
                    RCMRolloutRulesBusinessEntity configEnableEventCheckOnContainerPowerOff = objRCMHelperDal.GetProcessRuleConfig(RCMApplicationConstants.TerminalFreezeDown, RCMApplicationConstants.EnableEventCheckOnPowerOffContainerInMinutes);
                    double thresholdInMinutes;
                    if (configEnableEventCheckOnContainerPowerOff != null && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(configEnableEventCheckOnContainerPowerOff.Value) && Double.TryParse(configEnableEventCheckOnContainerPowerOff.Value, out thresholdInMinutes))
                    {
                        if (objTfdEntity.lastUnitEventDTTM >= DateTime.UtcNow.AddMinutes(-thresholdInMinutes))
                        {
                            break;
                        }
                    }
                    IsRuleValid = false;
                    reason = RCMApplicationConstants.ContainerPowerOff;
                }
                break;
            case RCMApplicationConstants.ConfirmLink:
                if (objTfdEntity.BookingLink == null
                ||
                (objTfdEntity.BookingLink != null &&
                !objTfdEntity.BookingLink.Equals(RCMApplicationConstants.ConfirmBookingLink, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase)))
                {
                    if (objTfdEntity.BookingLink != null && objTfdEntity.BookingLink.Equals(RCMApplicationConstants.TentativeBookingLink, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
                    {
                        bool customerExists = false;
                        RCMRolloutRulesBusinessEntity configTFDTentativeBookingException = objRCMHelperDal.GetProcessRuleConfig(RCMApplicationConstants.TerminalFreezeDown, RCMApplicationConstants.EnableExcludedCustomerTentativeBooking);
                        if (configTFDTentativeBookingException != null && configTFDTentativeBookingException.Value.Equals(RCMApplicationConstants.ConfigValueYes, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
                        {
                            RCMRkemEventHandlingDAL rckemdal = new RCMRkemEventHandlingDAL();
                            customerExists = rckemdal.CheckCustomerConfirmLink(objTfdEntity.EventLogID);
                        }
                        if (!customerExists)
                        {
                            IsRuleValid = false;
                            reason = RCMApplicationConstants.BookingLinkNotConfirm;// "Booking Link is not Confirm Link";
                        }
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        IsRuleValid = false;
                        reason = RCMApplicationConstants.BookingLinkNotConfirm;// "Booking Link is not Confirm Link";   
                    }
                }
                break;
            case RCMApplicationConstants.IsFrozenCargo:
                int lastReportingThresholdTFD = tfdConfig.LastReportedEventThreshold;

                RCMRkemEventHandlingDAL rkemdal = new RCMRkemEventHandlingDAL();
                var lastProcessedContainerdetails = rkemdal.GetContainerLastProcessedState(objTfdEntity.ContainerId);
                if (DateTime.UtcNow.AddHours(-lastReportingThresholdTFD) < lastProcessedContainerdetails.RCDEventDTTM)
                {
                    if ((objTfdEntity.CargoType == null)
                    ||
                    (objTfdEntity.CargoType != null && !(objTfdEntity.CargoType == (Int16)RCMApplicationConstants.ReeferCargoType.FrozenCargo)))
                    {
                        IsRuleValid = false;
                        reason = RCMApplicationConstants.CargoTypeNotFrozen;// "Cargo is not frozen";
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    IsRuleValid = false;
                    reason = RCMApplicationConstants.TFDContainerNotReporting;
                }

                break;
            case RCMApplicationConstants.MaxTempTFD:
                if ((objTfdEntity.BookedTemp == null)
                    ||
                    (objTfdEntity.BookedTemp != null && (objTfdEntity.BookedTemp > tfdConfig.MaxTemp)))
                {
                    IsRuleValid = false;
                    isBRToBeRetried = false;
                    reason = RCMApplicationConstants.BookedTempGreaterThanMaxTemp;// "BookedTemp is greater than max temp";
                }

                break;
            case RCMApplicationConstants.MinTempTFD:
                if ((objTfdEntity.BookedTemp == null)
                    ||
                   (objTfdEntity.BookedTemp != null && (objTfdEntity.BookedTemp < tfdConfig.MinTemp)))
                {
                    IsRuleValid = false;
                    isBRToBeRetried = false;
                    reason = RCMApplicationConstants.BookedTemplesserThanMinTemp; //"BookedTemp is lesser than min temp";
                }

                break;
            //case RCMApplicationConstants.FirmwareVersions:
            //    if ((objTfdEntity.FirmwareVersion == null)
            //        ||
            //        (objTfdEntity.FirmwareVersion != null && !tfdConfig.FirmwareVersions.Contains(objTfdEntity.FirmwareVersion)))
            //    {
            //        IsRuleValid = false;
            //        reason = RCMApplicationConstants.FirmwareVersionNotIncluded;// "Firmware version is not included in allowed firmware version";
            //    }
            //    break;
            case RCMApplicationConstants.ETAThresholdValue:
                if (objTfdEntity.VesselETA == null)
                {
                    reason = RCMApplicationConstants.VesselETANull;
                    IsRuleValid = false;
                    //By default isBRToBeRetried will be set to true for this scenario
                }
                else
                {
                    double bufferETAHours = 0;
                    //TFDVesselETABufferRollout is added for individual site level and global level. so if the Site is not Rollout then Global data will be picked
                    string profileValue = objHelper.GetDefinedAreaProfileValue(RCMApplicationConstants.GeoSite, objTfdEntity.SiteCode,
                                       RCMApplicationConstants.GeoSite, RCMApplicationConstants.TFDVesselETABufferRollout, RCMApplicationConstants.TerminalFreezeDown);
                    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(profileValue) && Convert.ToDouble(profileValue) > 0)
                    {
                        bufferETAHours = Convert.ToDouble(profileValue);
                    }
                    if (objTfdEntity.VesselETA.Value.AddHours(bufferETAHours) <= DateTime.UtcNow.AddHours(tfdConfig.ETAThresholdValue))
                    {
                        //checking the GSIS to get the latest VesselETA
                        DateTime? LatestVesselETA = GetVesselETA(objTfdEntity.VesselCode, objTfdEntity.BookingId, objTfdEntity.SiteCode, objTfdEntity.ContainerNumber, objTfdEntity.EventLogID);
                        //Comparing the lastestvesselETA from GSIS and Existing Vessel ETA
                        //if there is no change in VeselETAs, BR FAils and No Rescanning -code in else part will work
                        //if there is a change in VesselETA,if LatestVesselETA is greater than VesselETA -Compare value greater than 0
                        if (LatestVesselETA != null && DateTime.Compare(Convert.ToDateTime(LatestVesselETA), Convert.ToDateTime(objTfdEntity.VesselETA)) > 0)
                        {
                            //Latest Vessel ETA is updated to TFD table
                            objTFDDal.UpdateEventLogTFDWithETA(objTfdEntity.EventLogID, LatestVesselETA, "ETABR");
                            objTfdEntity.VesselETA = LatestVesselETA;
                            //Rechecking the BR of ETAThresholdValue with the updated ETA from GSIS, if it fails again no rescanning and BR Fails
                            if (objTfdEntity.VesselETA.Value.AddHours(bufferETAHours) <= DateTime.UtcNow.AddHours(tfdConfig.ETAThresholdValue))
                            {
                                isBRToBeRetried = false;
                                tfdReason = (Int16)RCMApplicationConstants.TFDReason.VesselETAThresholdExpired;
                                IsRuleValid = false;
                                reason = RCMApplicationConstants.EtaThresholdExpired;// "ETA threshold has expired"
                            }
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            isBRToBeRetried = false;
                            tfdReason = (Int16)RCMApplicationConstants.TFDReason.VesselETAThresholdExpired;
                            IsRuleValid = false;
                            reason = RCMApplicationConstants.EtaThresholdExpired;// "ETA threshold has expired";
                        }
                    }
                    if (!(objTfdEntity.VesselETA.Value.AddHours(bufferETAHours) <= DateTime.UtcNow.AddHours(tfdConfig.ETAThresholdValue)) && (objTfdEntity.VesselETA.Value <= DateTime.UtcNow.AddHours(tfdConfig.ETAThresholdValue)))
                    {
                        bufferETARuleSuccess = true;
                    }
                }
                break;
            case RCMApplicationConstants.containertypeexclusionlist:
                //fetch container type for container
                if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(tfdConfig.ContainerType))
                {
                    List<string> listContainerType = tfdConfig.ContainerType.Split(',').ToList();
                    int containerType = objRCMHelperDal.GetContainerType(objTfdEntity.ContainerId);
                    if ((containerType == -1) || listContainerType.Contains(containerType.ToString()))
                    {
                        IsRuleValid = false;
                        isBRToBeRetried = false;
                        reason = RCMApplicationConstants.ContainerTypeInExclusionList;// "Container Type is in exclusion list";
                    }
                }
                break;
            case RCMApplicationConstants.commoditiesexclusionlist:
                //fetch commodity type for container
                if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(tfdConfig.CommodityType))
                {
                    List<string> listCommodityType = tfdConfig.CommodityType.Split(',').ToList();
                    string commodityCode = objTFDDal.GetCommodityType(objTfdEntity.BookingId);

                    if (String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(commodityCode) || listCommodityType.Contains(commodityCode))
                    {
                        IsRuleValid = false;
                        isBRToBeRetried = false;
                        reason = RCMApplicationConstants.CommodityTypeInExclusionList;// "Commodity Type is in exclusion list";
                    }
                }
                break;
            case RCMApplicationConstants.customerexclusionlist:
                if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(tfdConfig.CustomerType))
                {
                    List<string> listCustomerType = tfdConfig.CustomerType.Split(',').ToList();
                    string customerType = objTFDDal.GetCustomerType(objTfdEntity.BookingId);

                    if (String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(customerType) || listCustomerType.Contains(customerType))
                    {
                        IsRuleValid = false;
                        isBRToBeRetried = false;
                        reason = RCMApplicationConstants.CustomerTypeInExclusionList;//"Customer Type is in exclusion list";
                    }
                }
                break;
            case RCMApplicationConstants.checkalarmstatus:

                //Not start TFD if MA is open or temporary closed
                bool checkmastatus = objTFDDal.CheckMAStatusOpen(objTfdEntity.ContainerId, tfdConfig);
                if (checkmastatus)
                {
                    IsRuleValid = false;
                    reason = RCMApplicationConstants.checkalarmstatus;
                }

                break;
            case RCMApplicationConstants.SiteCodeCheckForTFDRunningmode:
                if (listBusinessRules[cLoop].Value.Equals(RCMApplicationConstants.ConfigValueYes, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
                {
                    if (!ValidateSiteCodeAndTFDSupportedCommand(objTfdEntity.ContainerId, objTfdEntity.SiteCode))
                    {
                        IsRuleValid = false;
                        isBRToBeRetried = false;
                        reason = RCMApplicationConstants.SiteCodeCheckForTFDRunningModeFailed;// Need to modify
                        tfdReason = (Int16)RCMApplicationConstants.TFDReason.TFDNotEnabled;
                    }
                }
                break;
            default:
                RCMLogHandler.LogInfo("Rule:" + listBusinessRules[cLoop].Name + " is not handled", RCMLogHandler.LogType.General);
                break;

        }

        cLoop++;
    }
    //added for reporting tag to find the reefers which were failing due to threshold expired, but now is passing after adding buffer hours
    if (IsRuleValid && bufferETARuleSuccess)
    {
        objTFDDal.UpdateEventLogTFDChangeReportingTag(objTfdEntity.EventLogID, RCMApplicationConstants.ETABufferRuleValid);
    }
    return IsRuleValid;
}

What I’ve Tried:

I have attempted to optimize the ValidateBusinessRules method by leveraging a Dictionary to reduce lookup times. Despite this, I haven't observed any significant performance improvements, and the overall time complexity remains same.
Thought about refactoring repeated conditions, but need guidance on the best approach.

I would greatly appreciate recommendations on refactoring this method to improve readability, maintainability, and performance.

What performance measurements have you observed? Running this under a profiler reveals that which few lines are taking the bulk of the time?

Validation ends with the first invalid rule. Is that intentional? Validating all the rules then displaying the accumulated error messages is more efficient,  and the user will become very frustrated having to execute "validate" over and over and over ...

@J_H Nothing as of yet. Please suggest which one to use and how.

@radarbob the problem is the list has 75 rules(they are static, coming from DB) and we have 14 switch cases, that means for about 61 times the loop is executed for no reason.

@PranavBilurkar If "number of loops" is a KPI you care about, then instrument the code and report a loop counter at the end. If "elapsed time" is an important KPI, then get out your stopwatch or have the code record t0 = now() and then later elapsed = now() - t0. And I already advised to run a profiler so you can work on the few lines that matter rather than worry about the entire codebase.

61 times the loop is executed for no reason.  => Yes there is a reason. It is because they meet the loop conditions.  If 61 rules are irrelevant why are they in the list?  Off hand, code needs to be more selective on the DB end and/or more discriminating to enter the loop. That's rhetorical, comments is not a discussion forum.

difficult to maintain
is the most important issue you identify. Readability is mostly a result of maintainable code - good structure, naming, appropriate objects' functionality.  Performance is irrelevant until maintainability is resolved.

Tip: First Write Some Maintainable/Readable Code
Adding, removing, changing business rules will be scalable with appropriate classes: BusinessRules, Rule, etc.  Write more abstractly in terms of the business rules domain
forEach (rule in BusinessRules) rule.Validate();

console.WriteLine(BusinessRules.InvalidRules());   // implicit call ToString()


Code Infrastructure == Maintainability
Writing code outlines and/or snippets with "implementation-detail free" variable names (no "obj", "int", etc. in the names) can help identify needed objects (classes).  The class' infrastructure below may feel like overkill when "I just want to write a few lines of validating!" Infrastructure is just exactly that thing which makes everything readable, maintainable; the .NET framework is performant enough to not worry about it unless it becomes an obviously usability problem.
public class BusinessRules {
  public List<BusinessRule>  Rules { get; protected set }

  public BusinessRules() {
    Rules = new List<BusinessRule>();
  }

  public void Add (BusinessRule newRule) }
    if (newRule == null) return;

    this.Rules.Add(newRule);
  }

  public void Validate() {
    forEach (rule in Rules) rule.Validate();
  } 

if no valid rules return empty list BusinessRules collection
  public BusinessRules InvalidRules() {
    invalidRules = new BusinessRules();

    forEach(rule in this.Rules) 
      if (!rule.isValid()) invalidRules.Add(rule);

    return invalidRules;
  }

  public string ToString() { 
    StringBuilder me = new StringBuilder();
    
    forEach (rule in Rules) me.AppendLine(rule.ToString();
  
    return me.ToString();
  }
} // BusinessRules


abstract class == Maximum Flexibility
Each rule is a subclass. Write custom constructor for all needed parameters. Validate() is almost a straight cut-n-paste job and should not need a return type.
public abstract class BusinessRule {
  public bool IsValid {get; protected set;}
  // most of those global variables declared up front in the code
  // should be here.
  // If specific to a certain rule, put it in that Rule subclass.

  public BusinessRule() {
    // init all the global rule properties
  }

  public abstract void Validate() {  }

  public string ToString() {
    return $"Name : {this.Name} || IsValid: {this.IsValid} || ..."
}


I already have list with business rules added in it.

If there were Rule & BusinessRules classes - just wild speculation about the 61 wasted loops - instead of only one isRuleValid variable for all, each rule has its own isValid state and the collection class can have a method to set the irrelevant ones to "not valid". Or another method using some criteria to filter before looping.

Let's look at your method signature ️‍♂️
bool ValidateBusinessRules(
    RCMTFDBusinessEntity objTfdEntity,
    List<RCMRolloutRulesBusinessEntity> listBusinessRules, // just name and value
    RCMTFDConfigBusinessEntity tfdConfig,
    bool isSetInterimRulesSupported,

    out string businessRuleFailed,
    out string reason,
    out bool isBRToBeRetried,
    out Int16 tfdReason,
    bool isTFDCommandSupported = false)
{
//...
}

When I call a validate method, I expect to get a Validation result that contains Success or not and a list of Errors if they exist ... and your method have a lot of arguments try to keep your arguments as few as possible
look at this output parameters,
out string businessRuleFailed,
out string reason,
out bool isBRToBeRetried,
out Int16 tfdReason,

you can group them in an Immutable record
public record BusinessValidationError(string BusinessRuleName, string Reason, bool IsBRToBeRetried, Int16 TfdReason);

let's write a ValidationResult class to work as a return type and make it immutable to prevent a caller from change the result ... changes will be only in the validation process
public record ValidationResult(IEnumerable<BusinessValidationError> Errors)
{
    public bool IsSuccess => !IsError;
    public bool IsError => Errors.Any();
     
}

public class ValidationResultBuilder
{
    private List<BusinessValidationError> _errors = [];
    public void AddError(BusinessValidationError error)
    {
        if (error is null) return;
        _errors.Add(error);
    }
    public void AddErrors(IEnumerable<BusinessValidationError> errors)
    {
        _errors.AddRange(errors);
    }
    public ValidationResult GetResult()
    {
        return new ValidationResult(_errors);
    }    
}

Where to write Business Rule Code?
Single-responsibility principle says don't write a nuclar weapon code in single method, instead every object/method should be responsable for single task, So for each business rule, you need a different class knowing how to handle this rule, and to be self-aware how to validate a Business object (RCMTFDBusinessEntity) and tell us if it violates the rule or not
and all rules should inherit from a base Class or implement an interface to unify how to deal with them
public abstract class BusinessRuleHandler
{
    public string Name { get; } = "";

    public BusinessRuleHandler(string name)
    {
        Name = name;
    }

    public abstract ValidationResult Validate(RCMTFDBusinessEntity objTfdEntity);
}

and to add a business rule to your program, you just write a class that implant that abstract BusinessRuleHandler
For Example
public class ReeferTFDCapableRuleHandler : BusinessRuleHandler
{
    public ReeferTFDCapableRuleHandler() : base(RCMApplicationConstants.IsReeferTFDCapable)
    {
    }

    public override ValidationResult Validate(RCMTFDBusinessEntity objTfdEntity)
    {
        RCMHelper objHelper = new RCMHelper();
        ValidationResultBuilder  resultBuilder = new();

        if (!objHelper.IsReeferTFDCapable(objTfdEntity.ContainerNumber))
        {
            var error = new BusinessValidationError(
                BusinessRuleName : this.Name,
                Reason : RCMApplicationConstants.ReeferNotCapableForTFD,
                IsBRToBeRetried : false,
                TfdReason : (Int16)RCMApplicationConstants.TFDReason.TFDNotEnabled 
            );
            resultBuilder.AddError(error);
        }

        return resultBuilder.GetResult();
    }
}

the most important thing is that rule Handlers should be self-contained
and here are a few more examples on how to add new rules
public class OemSupportedRuleHandler : BusinessRuleHandler
{
    public OemSupportedRuleHandler() : base(RCMApplicationConstants.OemSupported)
    {
    }

    public override ValidationResult Validate(RCMTFDBusinessEntity objTfdEntity)
    {
        RCMHelper objHelper = new RCMHelper();
        ValidationResultBuilder resultBuilder = new();

        if (!objHelper.IsForwardCommandSupported(RCMApplicationConstants.TerminalFreezeDown, objTfdEntity.ContainerId))
        {
            var error = new BusinessValidationError(
                BusinessRuleName: this.Name,
                Reason: RCMApplicationConstants.OEMNotSupportedForTFD,
                IsBRToBeRetried: false,
                TfdReason: (Int16)RCMApplicationConstants.TFDReason.TFDNotEnabled 
            );
            resultBuilder.AddError(error);  
        }

        return resultBuilder.GetResult();
    }
}


public class ForwardCommandSupportedRuleHandler : BusinessRuleHandler
{
    private string commandName = "";
    public ForwardCommandSupportedRuleHandler(string commandName) : base(RCMApplicationConstants.ForwardCommandSupported)
    {
        this.commandName = commandName;
    }

    public override ValidationResult Validate(RCMTFDBusinessEntity objTfdEntity)
    {
        RCMHelper objHelper = new RCMHelper();
        ValidationResultBuilder resultBuilder = new();

        if (!objHelper.IsForwardCommandSupported(commandName, objTfdEntity.ContainerId))
        {
            var error = new BusinessValidationError(
               BusinessRuleName: this.Name,
               Reason: RCMApplicationConstants.FWDCmdNotSupported,
               IsBRToBeRetried: false,
               TfdReason: (Int16)RCMApplicationConstants.TFDReason.TFDNotEnabled
           );
            resultBuilder.AddError(error); 
        }

        return resultBuilder.GetResult();
    }
}


public class ContainerPowerOnRuleHandler : BusinessRuleHandler
{
    public ContainerPowerOnRuleHandler() : base(RCMApplicationConstants.ContainerPowerOn)
    {
    }

    public override ValidationResult Validate(RCMTFDBusinessEntity objTfdEntity)
    {
        var resultBuilder = new ValidationResultBuilder();
        RCMHelperDAL objRCMHelperDal = new RCMHelperDAL();
        if (objTfdEntity.PowerIndicator != RCMApplicationConstants.PowerIndicatorOn)
        {
            // Code to handle, if container power indicator is OFF but unit telemetry is recieving in RCM EC in last configured hours then will allow reefer for further processing. 
            RCMRolloutRulesBusinessEntity configEnableEventCheckOnContainerPowerOff = objRCMHelperDal.GetProcessRuleConfig(RCMApplicationConstants.TerminalFreezeDown, RCMApplicationConstants.EnableEventCheckOnPowerOffContainerInMinutes);
            double thresholdInMinutes;
            if (configEnableEventCheckOnContainerPowerOff != null && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(configEnableEventCheckOnContainerPowerOff.Value) && Double.TryParse(configEnableEventCheckOnContainerPowerOff.Value, out thresholdInMinutes))
            {
                if (objTfdEntity.lastUnitEventDTTM < DateTime.UtcNow.AddMinutes(-thresholdInMinutes))
                {
                    var error = new ValidationError(
                        BusinessRuleName: this.Name,
                        Reason: RCMApplicationConstants.ContainerPowerOff,
                        IsBRToBeRetried: false,
                        TfdReason: (Int16)RCMApplicationConstants.TFDReason.TFDNotEnabled
                    );
                    resultBuilder.AddError(error);
                }
            }            
        }
        return resultBuilder.GetResult();
    }
}

Rewrite your method
actually you only need two parameters, the object you need to validity and a list of business rule to cheek against
ValidationResult ValidateRules( RCMTFDBusinessEntity objTfdEntity, List<BusinessRuleHandler> BusinessRules)
{
    ValidationResultBuilder resultBuilder = new();
    
    foreach (BusinessRuleHandler ruleHandler in BusinessRules) 
    {
        RCMLogHandler.LogInfo("BusinessRule Being Validate: " + ruleHandler.Name, RCMLogHandler.LogType.General);
        var ruleValidationResult = ruleHandler.Validate(objTfdEntity);
        if (ruleValidationResult.IsError)
        {
            resultBuilder.AddErrors(ruleValidationResult.Errors);
        }
    }

    return resultBuilder.GetResult();
}

now it's look really simple and cute code  more over, you can make unit test Super easy
Compatible with existing code
you can use the old method signature, but you should mark it as Obsolete
[Obsolete]
bool ValidateBusinessRules(
    RCMTFDBusinessEntity objTfdEntity,
    List<RCMRolloutRulesBusinessEntity> listBusinessRules,
    RCMTFDConfigBusinessEntity tfdConfig,
    bool isSetInterimRulesSupported,

    out string businessRuleFailed,
    out string reason,
    out bool isBRToBeRetried,
    out Int16 tfdReason,
    bool isTFDCommandSupported = false)
{

    businessRuleFailed = "";
    reason = null;
    tfdReason = (Int16)RCMApplicationConstants.TFDReason.ProcessNotstartedDueToBRFailure;
    isBRToBeRetried = true;
    
    var rules = GetBusinessRuleHandlers(listBusinessRules,tfdConfig, isSetInterimRulesSupported, isTFDCommandSupported);

    var result = ValidateRules(objTfdEntity, rules);

    if (result.IsError)
    {
        var error = result.Errors.First();
        businessRuleFailed = error.BusinessRuleName??"";
        reason = error.Reason;
        tfdReason = error.TfdReason;
        isBRToBeRetried = error.IsBRToBeRetried;
    }
    
    return result.IsSuccess;
}

List<BusinessRuleHandler> GetBusinessRuleHandlers(List<RCMRolloutRulesBusinessEntity> listBusinessRules,
    RCMTFDConfigBusinessEntity tfdConfig,
    bool isSetInterimRulesSupported,
    bool isTFDCommandSupported)
{
    List<BusinessRuleHandler> businessRuleHandlers = [];
    string commandName = isSetInterimRulesSupported ? RcmFwdCmdConstants.SetInterimTempCommandName : isTFDCommandSupported ? RcmFwdCmdConstants.TerminalFreezeDown : RcmFwdCmdConstants.ChangeTempCmdName; //  Using TerminalFreezeDown constant for checking command for TFD
    foreach (var rule in listBusinessRules) 
    {
        BusinessRuleHandler handler = rule.Name switch
        {
            RCMApplicationConstants.IsReeferTFDCapable => new ReeferTFDCapableRuleHandler(),
            RCMApplicationConstants.OemSupported => new OemSupportedRuleHandler(),
            RCMApplicationConstants.ForwardCommandSupported => new ForwardCommandSupportedRuleHandler(commandName),
            RCMApplicationConstants.ContainerPowerOn => new ContainerPowerOnRuleHandler(),
            //-- etc...
            _ => throw new NotImplementedException()
        };
        businessRuleHandlers.Add(handler);
    }
    return businessRuleHandlers;
}


Thanks for your comment and suggestions!
